# .container is not showing below .navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstreap 3. My code is below div `.navbar` is showing properly on top.
But problem is with `.container` it is not showing below the `.navbar`
What change should I make to work it properly

```
 <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Office</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right top-margin">
                    <form  class="form-inline" method="post" action="login">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userName" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs10">Join us</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add padding to the top of the `body` for fixed navbars:

`body { padding-top: 70px; }`

From the docs:

> The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add
>   padding to the top of the <body>. Try out your own values or use our
>   snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.